# How to make the default destructor non-inline?

Tags: c++, c++11, inline, destructor, unique-ptr

How can one force the compiler to make the default destructor of a class non-inline?

One way of doing this is to write an empty destructor definition, but it feels messy and also you get a warning from the static analyzer (*clang-tidy* in my case), that `= default` should be used for a trivial destructor.

To elaborate more on the actual use case - the goal is to have something similar to:

*MyClass.h*

```
class MyClassImpl;

class MyClass {
    std::unique_ptr<MyClassImpl> m_impl;
public:
    MyClass();
    // and some other methods
};
```

A `std::unique_pointer` to an incomplete type, which is forward declared in the header and the definition is known only in the source file.

The code above will give a compiler error:

```
error: use of undefined type 'MyClassImpl'
```

The actual problem is, that the default destructor of `MyClass` generated by the compiler is inline and so it needs the complete type info of `MyClassImpl`.

This can be fixed by adding an empty destructor for `MyClass` (by declaring in the header and defining in the source file, since defining in the header will implicitly make it inline which will cause the same error).

But is this the only way in modern C++?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just implement it in cpp file as ordinary method:

MyClass.h

```
class MyClassImpl;

class MyClass {
    std::unique_ptr<MyClassImpl> m_impl;
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass() /*noexcept*/;

    // and some other methods
};
```

in cpp

```
MyClass::~MyClass() /*noexcept*/ = default;
```

Comment: Did not know that `default` can be used for separate definition, good to know.

Comment: This will work because the `cpp` file will already have an `include` of the header in which `MyClassImpl` is fully defined. All the other methods of `MyClass` will be needing this as well.

Comment: @Slava: Notice that it is a little different than putting it inside the class (user provided, is_trivially_destructible, ...).

Comment: Nice, didn't know `default` can be used outside of the class definition.